# How to return '0' if date doesn't exist when using MAX

Tags: sql

I'm trying to find the most recent date value in a column for every inspection realized on a device. But there is some devices that never had any inspections. I still need need to get some return.

For example:

```
device number    date inspected
-------------------------------
     01          2015-01-01,
     01          2021-03-05,
     02 
     03          2022-01-01
```

Expected output using max:

```
01    2021-03-05
02    0 
03    2022-01-01
```

This is my SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    dbo.DEVICE.NUMBER AS device number,
    MAX(dbo.DEVICE.DATE) AS Date
```

I can't seem to find how to do it properly

Comment: `COALESCE(MAX(dbo.DEVICE.DATE), 0)`, though there may not be a way to do this if datatypes per column are enforced, unless you return both as strings, or the date in unixtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn any NULL into a desired default value with this function:

```
COALESCE(MAX(dbo.DEVICE.DATE), 0)
```

It's not obvious that `0` will be a valid date value, so `'0'` might
work better.
I have seen folks use sentinel values like `'1000-01-01'`
or even nonsensical strings like `'0000-00-00'`
to cope with such type details.
If January 1st 1970 works for your application,
just use that as start-of-epoch.